# EF Core define query using list instead of dbset in dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In EF Core using the `modelBuilder` a query can be defined for keyless entities like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UrlResource>()
    .ToInMemoryQuery(() => context.Blogs.Select(b => new UrlResource { Url = b.Url }));
```

For unit testing I would like to use a list for the query instead of a dbset, like this:

```
var urlResources = new List<UrlResource>() { ... }.AsQueryable();

modelBuilder.Entity<UrlResource>()
    .ToInMemoryQuery(() => urlResources);
```

But in that case I get an exception with the `The LINQ expression could not be translated.` message.

Or for this ...

```
var urlResources = new List<UrlResource>() { ... };

modelBuilder.Entity<UrlResource>()
    .ToInMemoryQuery(() => urlResources.AsQueryable());
```

... this exception:

`` System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UrlResource]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[UrlResource]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[UrlResource] Where[UrlResource](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[UrlResource], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[UrlResource,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg0') ``

I tested several variations without success.

Does anybody know a way how to solve this problem?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!